# Populate from One Model to Another Using Mongoose/MongoDB in Node/Express Application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-populate

I am struggling to understand the **populate** method in **Mongoose**, while having trouble populating fields from one Mongoose model to another. The first model Schema is:

```
var MprnSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    mprNo: {type: Number, unique: true, required: true},
    siteName: String,
    buildingNo: Number,
    streetAddress: String,
    secondAddress: String,
    townCity: String,
    postCode: String,
    supplier: String,
    siteContactName: String,
    siteContactNo: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Mprn", MprnSchema);
```

And another Schema is:

```
var FaultSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    jobRef: Number,
    mprNo: Number,
    requestedDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    attendedDate: {type: Date, default: null},
    siteDetails: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Mprn'},
    faultIssue: String,
});
```

However, when I try to populate the 'siteDetails' with the contents of Mprn, I get **[]** when using thhe code below:

```
  Fault.find(reportQuery).populate('siteDetails', 'siteName 
postCode').exec((err, faultResults) => {
        if(err){
              req.flash("error", err.message);
              res.redirect("/");
        }

        console.log(faultResults);
        res.render("reportResults", { queryResults: faultResults });   

        });
```

The object passed to be rendered (**queryResults**) only contains the **Fault** data and NOT the 'siteDetails' that should be populated. I think the problem may be when I am using the Fault.Create() method in the first place, should I be saving a reference to the MPRN model at this point, so that the there is an **Id** to be referenced when populating?

My samples collections are:

**Fault**

```
  {
    "jobRef": 60000,
    "mprNo": 123456,
    "faultIssue": "Test"
  }
```

**Mprn**

```
 {
    "mprNo": 123456,
    "siteName": "Smithson Gates",
    "buildingNo": 76,
    "streetAddress": "Garden Place",
    "secondAddress": "Greater Manchester",
    "townCity": "Salford",
    "postCode": "M5 3AP",
    "supplier": "test",
    "siteContactName": "Mr B Jones",
    "siteContactNo": "0161 000 0000"
 }
```

Comment: can you post your sample collection?

Comment: I have added the collection data that I am testing this with. These Schemas are actually larger and I have truncated them to a minimum and have added the test data that is applicable.

Comment: which is the common (matching key) in both the collections? and what is your mongodb version?

Comment: Apologies, the key is mprNo that is matching in each collections ( i have updated the mprNo value) and the MongoDB version is V4.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are using latest version of mongodb... So, You can try below [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation... and the plus point of using this is you don't need to store `_id` of `Mprn` collection in the `Fault`... You can easily join both the collections with `mprn` number

```
Fault.aggregate([
  { "$match": reportQuery },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Mprn.collection.name,
    "let": { "mprNo": "$mprNo" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$mprNo", "$$mprNo" ] } } }
    ],
    "as": "siteDetails"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$siteDetails" }
])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure how I would use this within an express/Node route?

Comment: this is an aggregate query just like a find query of mongodb and also the alternate of populate query... just replace this with your find().populate() query it will work as same and give your desired result... you will learn a lot of things about mongodb after using this query...

Comment: Thanks for all your help, but now I am getting db is not defined, should i be replacing **db** with something else? I am having severe brain-freeze today...

Comment: It should be `Fault`... And `Mprn.collection.name` is the name of your `Mprn` collection... you need to import it just  you have imported `Fault`

Comment: Thanks it worked! I am going to go an investigate aggregates in more depth now. Thanks for all your help!